# fancy box gallery: How to prevent that a click switch to next content?

Tags: jquery, fancybox-2

1. I have miscellaneous gallery with images and frames (which include videos). When fancybox shows the video then a click to the control button play / pause of the video switch to the next image / iframe instead of playing or pausing the video. How can I prevent this trigger?
2. HTML & Script (sorry, I tried one hour to format this code piece correctly but didn't get it…)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.5"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.6"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".fbox_mix").fancybox({
        'padding'   : 2,
        'nextClick'   : false,
        'closeClick'      : false,
        'overlayShow' : false,
        'hideOnContentClick': false
        });
    });
</script>
<a title="XXX" class="fbox_mix" data-fancybox-group="group_OMS" href="images/zusammen/gal_oms/20100623es011.jpg">Mehr Bilder</a>
<a title="XXX" class="fbox_mix" data-fancybox-group="group_OMS" href="images/zusammen/gal_oms/20100623es016.jpg"></a>
<a title="XXX" class="fbox_mix" data-fancybox-group="group_OMS" href="images/zusammen/gal_oms/20100623es025.jpg"></a>
und <a class="fbox_mix fancybox.iframe" data-fancybox-group="group_OMS" title="'Trailer OMS" href="http://www.youtube.com/v/vu4v0KxTg3s&fs=1">Video-Trailer.</a>
```

In addition, I include several galleries. The entire page can be seen at: http://www.erichpick.info/zusammen.shtml

Thank you very much!

Comment: the issue is that fancybox navigation arrows (area) is on top of the videos so it voids accessing the video controls. The workaround is to move the fancybox navigation area out of the box. Check http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#useful No.5